# Xubuntu 16.04 log out menu won't go away

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, logout

Fresh install of Xubuntu 16.04 i386 on a Viewsonic VOT132

After a few minutes, the "Log out" box pops up on its own. Pressing escape will make it disappear, but it always pops right back up within a few moments.

This makes the machine unusable.

CPU/GPU temps are stable and within expectations.

Power button is not stuck, nor is sleep button.

Does it even if keyboard / mouse are disconnected.

I'm at my wits end.  Any ideas?

Comment: Update:  Seems to only occur when the system is under load.  If I close down any CPU intensive operations, the issue ceases.  As soon as I open Youtube or Facebook, it begins again.  I'm thinking it has to be temperature related, but the sensors command shows everything within spec.  Any ideas?

Comment: I now believe it is a hardware call to power down.  Maybe a hidden BIOS issue due to temperatures.  When I went into power manager and disabled the power button dialog, it stopped occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Went into power manager and set power button dialog to "Do Nothing" this appears to have stopped the behavior.  I believe it is a BIOS issue with temperature, but not 100% certain, as there is no setting in bios to power down when overheating.  The sensors command does not show over heating, but this issue only occurred when the system was under load and the fan was running at high speed.